# Spring yaml does not work on aws server

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have a spring boot app with this yaml:

```
    ---
spring:
    profiles: production
server:
    port: 8080

servicesUrl:
  aaa:  aaa.aaa.aaa:9090
```

I create the jar using gradle assemble.

When I run it locally:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.acitve=production -jar aaa.jar
```

All works well.

I scp the jar to the server and when I run the exact same command  I get:

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aaaController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'servicesUrl.aaa' in value "${servicesUrl.aaa}"
```

I have to state that the different ports are being served according to the profile, both locally and AWS.

This is the line in the class:

```
@Value("${servicesUrl.aaa}")
private String aaaServiceUrl;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: One thing I noticed is you've defined `-jar` twice.

Comment: It is just a typo

Answer (score 1):

Your YAML file seems to have an issue:

```
    ---
spring:
    profiles: production
server:
    port: 8080

servicesUrl:
  aaa:  aaa.aaa.aaa:9090
```

YAML accepts 2 spaces indention only. If you mix indention with `\t` or 4 spaces then your file wont be parsed correctly. Here is what your YAML file should look like:

```
---
spring:
  profiles: production
server:
  port: 8080

servicesUrl:
  aaa:  aaa.aaa.aaa:9090
```

There is also a typo in your `java` command (word "acitve"):

```
java -Dspring.profiles.acitve=production -jar aaa.jar
```

it should be:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar aaa.jar
```

Comment: @IdoBarash maybe it's caused by the typo in your command. I've updated the answer.

Comment: No worries, you've moved forwards and this is most important. Good luck!

Comment: @IdoBarash you can accept my answer if it helped fixing you the issue. Thx in advance! :)